# Add SQL data to default JPARepostiroty method

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a `JpaRepository`:

```java
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Entity, Integer>
```

And I have a default method inside:

```java
Page<Entity> findAllByBookIdAndStatus(Integer bookId, PostStatus postStatus, Pageable pageable);
```

And the method above doesn't sort my data, just return in no particular order.

So if I want to have my data sorted, can I add some SQL data to this method e.g. `ORDER BY ENTITY_ID` and to not write new SQL query?

Is it possible and if yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you add the code block where you call the `findAllByBookIdAndStatus` method?

Comment: You can update pageable object with sorting order with column.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45104047/spring-jpa-find-by-and-order-by) out?

Something like this should work.

```
Page<Entity> findAllByBookIdAndStatusOrderByIdAsc(
    Integer bookId,
    PostStatus postStatus,
    Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this :

- writing a query with the @Query anotation and using the proper syntaxe to order the response (depends of the DBMS you're using)
- or you can itterate the reponse in the service layer to order them

personnaly i would use the first method

Answer (score 0):

You can add sorting info into pageable object with page and size when create pageable object.

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(1, 10, new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "ENTITY_ID"))
```